# Can you add another stove to an existing circuit?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, oven, stove, canada

Suppose you wanted to put a second oven next to the existing oven in your kitchen. Could you simply add a second receptacle to the circuit?

Hypothetically speaking, suppose your stoves were a Kenmore 970-678534, and a C970-502123, and your circuit had a 40AMP breaker and I'm not sure what the gauge the wire is, but it's fat, much fatter than the dryer cable. Hypothetically.

Comment: why are you asking a hypothetical question?

Comment: @jsotola My best guess is "I already did this and now I have second thoughts and am worried that maybe it was a really bad thing to do but I don't want to admit it."

Comment: Can you post the nameplate wattages of both appliances?

Comment: Also, are these built-in ovens, slide-in ranges, or free-standing appliances?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel 10.6 & 13 kw @ 120/240 volts, 60 hz, free standing.

Comment: @manassehkatz I haven't done it. In fact my wife has stated she doesn't even want it. I'm asking out of curiosity.

Comment: @ShemSeger OK. The "hypothetical" was getting us all confused.

Answer (score 1):

### Nope

NEC 210.23(C) limits 40A and 50A multioutlet branch circuits in dwelling units to powering *fastened in place* (i.e. built-in) cooking appliances, not freestanding ones.  (A regular range circuit only has a single outlet, so it is governed by NEC 210.22 instead.)

Your 40A branch circuit could power either range, though, as a 13kW nameplate range comes out as 8.4kW of demand-factored load when you apply Table 220.55, note 1 to it, and NEC 422.10(A), paragraph 4 expressly permits the table 220.55 branch factors to be applied to household cooking appliance circuits.

Comment: Do you happen to know how similar the NEC and CSA are? I live in Canada.

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetically, no. Realistically, also no. Legally, still no.

Comment: I wouldn't go that far, not without 220.55 numbers in hand at least.

Comment: I know I've seen some other answers recently regarding 2 dryer receptacles on one circuit. I'm not so sure it is prohibited. Hypothetically :-)

Comment: @manassehkatz because the Code for 30A circuits says nothing to prohibit multiple receptacles, and other code is permissive.  The Code for 40A and 50A receptacles explicitly outlaws multiple receptacles.  I believe it's NEC 240.4?

Comment: @Harper -- 210.23(C) is the governing Code here, as mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on your watt numbers, the breaker couldn't power one of those, let alone two.

A 40A breaker is good for 9.6KW at redline.

That won't cover even the smaller 10.6kw load, let alone the 13kw load.

I would say the one should be installed with a 50A breaker (12kw) and #6 wire, unless the instructions say to do something else, in which case follow the instructions.    The other one should use a 60A breaker (14.4kw) also with #6 wire.  Each one will max out its circuit.

You are not allowed to put two receptacles on a 40-50A circuit, nor can you put those receptacles on any other size of circuit.  Each will need its own circuit.

Comment: Actually, a 13kW range fits onto a 40A circuit as it's only 8.4kW of demand-factored load once you apply Table 220.55, note 1 procedures and the last paragraph of 422.10(A).